# obtener los datos de una lista con jquery

Tags: jquery

bueno esa es mi inquietud, mediante ajax recibo los objetos en una lista,

```
listaConfiguracionSucursales = data.lista;
```

quiero saber si habra alguna manera de obtener todos los datos de un determinado campo de esa lista, actualmente solo recibo un valor de un campo determinado de la siguiente  manera `ipControlador = listaConfiguracionSucursales[$("#comboboxSucursales").val()].ipControlador;`

los datos de la lista que quiero obtener pertenecen al campo ipControlador, pero quiero la lista completa, intente con un ciclo for, pero no me los muestra en la vista, alguna sugerencia? les agradezco

actualmente esta es la forma en la que intente obtener los datos de dicha lista con el ciclo for

```
        .post(
                    'ConsultasRms/tabla_consultaProductos.html',
                    formulario.serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        $("#loading").hide();

        comboSucursales = document.getElementById('comboboxSucursales');
                    sucursalConsulta = comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].text;
                    console.log('contenido1',sucursalConsulta);

                          ipControladores = data.lista;
                          console.log('listaCOMPLETA',ipControladores);

                               for(z = 0; z < ipControladores.length; z++){

                                var datarow = {
                                    sucursal: sucursalConsulta,
                                    numeroSucursal: comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].value,
                                    ip: ipControladores[z].ipControlador,

                                };

                                var su = jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                    .jqGrid('addRowData', cont, datarow);
                                    cont++;                 
                           }
```

Answer (score 3):

> quiero saber si habra alguna manera de obtener todos los datos de un determinado campo de esa lista

La respuesta es obviamente iterando. Dices que "no muestra nada en la vista" qué es un comentario demasiado genérico, pero supongo estás comentiendo errores en la iteración. Te dejo dos formas, la actual y la clásica.

**ES2015**:

```
lista.forEach(item => {
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(item)) {
    // aquí k -> llave, v -> valor
  }
});
```

**Tradicional**:

```
lista.forEach(function (lista) {
  for (var key in item) {
    var val = item[key];
    // key -> llave, val -> valor
  }
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$.each(lista, function () {
  for (var key in this) {
    var val = this[key];
    // key -> llave, val -> valor
  }
});
```

Esto lo único que hace es iterar una lista de objetos (`{}`) y por cada item iterar sus entradas.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, voy a probar de esa manera, en la edicion deje la forma en la que intente obtener los valores de dicho campo en la lista, la cual no me funciono, te agradezco si la chequeas y me indiques en donde podria estar el error

Comment: Deberías poner el formato de tu lista, ya que la iteración dependerá de ella. Así mismo, deberías estar todo el tiempo depurando o, en su defecto, imprimiendo variables y datos obtenidos para saber en primer lugar **si están llegando o almacenando los valores que se esperan**.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo puedes usar la funcion each

```
$.each(data[i].description, function (index, value)
                    {
                        if(index == lang)
                        {
                            option += value;
                        }
                    });
```

o el foreach que te comenta el amigo en la respuesta de arriba. como es jquery con la funcion each deberia realizar el recorridod e la lista. puedes utilizarlo dentro de tu form para recorrer la lista y el each para sacar el campo que deseas.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo